# How to check if a file is in a specific directory or its subdirectories in C

Tags: c, subdirectory

I am building my own shell and I was wondering: how can I know if a commande  is on the directory "/bin" and its subdirectories.
I would like to implement a function char* path_to_command(char* commandname) which return the path of a command given in parameters.

I've been looking for functions which determine if a specific file is in a directory (like fopen, or access). But those functions just tell us if the file is in the directory only. 
I was thinking about a recursive function with fopen, where I would have to use strcat a lots of time.
I believe that there is a better solution.

English is not my native language, I'm very sorry if there are mistakes.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `which(1)`? https://linux.die.net/man/1/which

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write the recursive function by yourself, prefer use of the standard [nftw](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//functions/nftw.html):

> **NAME**
>
> nftw - walk a file tree
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <ftw.h>
>
> int nftw(const char *path, int (*fn)(const char *,
>          const struct stat *, int, struct FTW *), int fd_limit, int flags);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The nftw() function shall recursively descend the directory hierarchy
>   rooted in path.

But, for a standard shell there is no need to search recursively (worst, that would be very weird for any user), you just need to search in directories mentioned in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! That was exactly what I was looking for.
Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 0):

you need to look at the directory content, look at the functions *opendir* / *readdir* / *closedir* (`#include <dirent.h>`)

{edit add}

Take care, when you scan the content of a directory you will reach the directories "." and "..", do not go recursively into them because "." is the current directory and ".." the upper directory (except for "/" where ".." is also "/")

Answer (score 0):

You could not only use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) & [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) & `closedir` but you probably want to *construct* some file path in a string (using string routines like `snprintf` or [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)) and use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) or [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) on it (since `readdir` returns a directory entry, whose `d_name` you would combine with the path of the containing directory).

You could also use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html).

However, inside a shell, you just want to iterate on the components of the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), and append the program name to each of them. For that point a recursive descent is not needed. And there is also [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html).